# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом И в этом предложении?

Tags: запятые, сложное-предложение

***Он был художником, она — королевой и оба понимали, что обречены, но оттого лишь сильнее любили**.*

Вопрос принципиальный. Автор утверждает, что **грамматика** ему вообще не нужна. Если бы он думал о грамматическом разборе, о предикативных основах и прочих никчемных вещах, то не написал бы ни строчки.

Возможно, он ставит знаки препинания интуитивно, в том числе с учетом интонации. Но вот  запятой перед союзом И нет, **а нужна ли там запятая?** Можно ли объяснить ее отсутствие, используя правила?

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Проблема такая. При постановке запятой по правилам текст делится на несколько частей согласно грамматической структуре. При отсутствии запятой текст делится **на две части** союзом НО. Вероятно, именно так его надо читать, и тогда отсутствие запятой кажется обоснованным, но правилами это сложно объяснить.

По правилам надо записать так: *Он был художником, она — королевой и оба понимали, что обречены, но оттого **они** лишь сильнее любили друг друга*.
Но здесь излишек местоимений, что нежелательно. Автор же просто убрал "лишнюю" запятую.

Comment: А вопрос-то с наскока не решить. Тут можно, я думаю, увидеть перечисление (и тогда запятая перед "и" не нужна, потому что этот союз присоединяет третье звено перечисления). Но по смыслу запятая нужна, как мне кажется, потому что "оба" -- это уже обобщение к ранее идущим двум звеньям. А как бы вы сами разобрали это предложение?

Comment: Какое здесь перечисление, какое обобщение?Грамматика такова:  бессоюзная и сочинительная связь трех предикативных основ, причем третье предложение включает придаточное и однородные сказуемые. Запятая нужна. Но это грамматика, а по семантике оно вроде бы делится на две части союзом НО,. Но ладно, оставим на завтра...